# Cannot properly send email in MacOS via postfix

Tags: systemd, email, postfix, macos, smtp

Telling story short.
My MacOS version is: 12.4.

## In /etc/postfix/:

In *sasl_passwd* i have:

```
smtp.emailsrvr.com:587 <myEmail>:<password>
```

In *main.cf* i have:

```
# custom POSTFIX email sender config
relayhost = smtp.emailsrvr.com:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
# also tried AUTH LOGIN in the line above
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

My default DNS in network settings is 8.8.8.8 - standart Google DNS.

I did the *postmap*(ing) of my *sasl_passwd*, *postfix* reloading…
At first time after sending emails via:

```
sudo echo "testing testing test email" | mail -s test <someTargetEmail>
```

i got `SASL Authorization error`, when used in *sasl_passwd* my gmail account.

Then found info about need to enable in gmail account something like `"ACCESS OF ANOTHER SOURCES"` kinda.
Then changed my origin email from *sasl_passwd* to another one from @bk.ru domain.

After again redoing/restarting things finally when i send email - no error occured, i got the email id and description in *mailq*:

```
"-Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
B7BD6301AB98DC*     305 Fri Jun 17 23:23:49  mac@Mac.local
                                         <targetEmail>"
```

But no message was found in the *targetEmail* account everywhere.
Can someone help me understand the situation and resolve the problem, thanx.